# Unique pairs of animals adjacent to the fox

Tags: untagged

Playing with this fox scoring card:

[image]

[Rules](https://www.alderac.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Cascadia-Rules.pdf) say:

> Score for each fox, an increasing number of points based on the number of unique
> animal pairs (not including other fox pairs) directly adjacent to it. As pictured, pairs of other animals do not need to be adjacent to each other

**How many points does that fox score?**

I'm tempted to say **3** as each elk can be paired with two other elks so we can't have a unique pair of elks but I'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: To me unique pair reads as if you have 4 elks and 2 fishes, you would still have only 2 pairs there that are unique and not 3 pairs for the counting. Without even knowing the game, just by wording and the card it should be 5 points.